# Why am I still able to fetch data, even with deleting FireStore object in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I deleted an entry in the Firestore and also checked it manually to confirm that. However, as long as I do not close the application, I can send a request to fetch the data and I still get the result. This should not be the case.

If you imagine having a shared photo with some textual information and you delete those information, this would mean, other users can still see the textual information (fetched from the Firestore) but not the image anymore (store in Firestorage).

I want to display a message on the UI, something like "The content does not exist anymore".

How I can achieve that? I used the following approach so far but it does not work at the moment:

```
public func checkIfChallengeObjectExists(completionHandler:@escaping(Bool)->(), challengeId:String) {
    CHALLENGE_COLLECTION?.document(challengeId).getDocument(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }

        if (querySnapshot?.documentID == "" || querySnapshot!.metadata.isFromCache) {
                completionHandler(false)
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have Persistence enabled? Also it looks like you're ignoring potential errors with querySnapshot? and querySnapshot!. You should probably add something like this `guard let doc = documentSnapshot?.data() else { display error and return }` to safely handle optionals and protect your code.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `addSnapshotListener` instead of `getDocument`? The former will trigger when the document is altered in any way (or in your case, deleted). `getDocument` is for when you want to get data once and one time only. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift

Answer (score 2):

Non-existent documents will still return document snapshots, but they will be empty. Therefore, you must check the contents of the snapshot for the document, not the snapshot itself. Also, you should handle errors and the overall flow of the return better.

```
public func checkIfChallengeObjectExists(completionHandler:@escaping(Bool)->(), challengeId:String) {
    CHALLENGE_COLLECTION?.document(challengeId).getDocument(completion: { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let doc = querySnapshot,
           doc.exists {
            completionHandler(true) // only one possible true condition
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            completionHandler(false) // all else false
        }
    })
}
```

As a side note, I recommend reordering the parameters of the function to make it easier to read when called (conventionally, the completion handler comes last) and giving the boolean argument a name so it's easier to read when referencing (sometime later or by other developers).

```
public func verifyChallengeObject(ID: String, _ completion: @escaping (_ exists: Bool) -> Void) {
    ...
}

verifyChallengeObject(ID: "abc123", { (exists) in
    if exists {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello @bsod. You are a legend! Thanks for the reply. This solved my issue